# Remote build in ionic pro fails - cannot find module './_rules'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, ionic-view

I just upgraded my ionic legacy app to the ionic pro platform.

Following some steps to link my existing app to the ionic pro I had to run this command :

```
$ git push ionic master
```

which triggers a new remote build.
This build fails stating :

```
Error: Cannot find module './_rules'
```

Googling for this _rules doesn't get me any further.

When I run this build on my local machine

```
ionic build --prod
```

Then everything goes well..

---

Installation : 
cli packages:

> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
>
> global packages:
>
> Cordova CLI : 6.5.0
>
> local packages:    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
>        Cordova Platforms  : android 6.1.2 ios 4.3.1
>       Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.0
>
> System:
>
> ios-deploy : 1.9.1 ios-sim    : 5.0.13    Node       : v7.5.0   npm
>   : 4.1.2    OS         : macOS Sierra Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build
>   version 8E3004b

**EDIT :** 
My current app.module.ts file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oazatwyayer9chb/app.module.ts?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me the file directory which you define for the code
`Error: Cannot find module './_rules'`
I think the problem is not with the code, it is with the file name and its path.
This can solve your problem if you import correct file name with its path in your **app.module.ts**.

Like: If the file is present in the same folder you can use below code

```
import { PageName } from 'filename';
```

Comment: Problem is I don't have a file with a name like '_rules'
It is quite a basic application with some components but anything related to something named '_rules' is new to me..

Comment: @RobrechtVM, Can you show me the file  'app.module.ts'.

Comment: There is a link to my app.module.ts file in the original post now.

Comment: @RobrechtVM Your 'app.module.ts' file is fine. Sorry, but I didn't have any idea about your error. Might be some one will help you.